# Can I view or export the nodes of a decision tree in a text format?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using random forests via the `RandomForestClassifier` in scikit-learn and would like to examine the decision criteria on the nodes of the resulting decision trees. I can see a way to access a particular `DecisionTreeClassifier` after fitting (via `RandomForestClassifier.ensemble_[i]`), and I can see a way to export a tree to produce a graphviz image (via `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz()`). However I can't see a way to describe the tree in any way simpler than an image - in particular I would just like a human-readable text format.

Specifically: the graphviz tree image contains text on each node describing the decision criteria and results at that node. What I would like is to be able to produce this per-node text, and a specification of which nodes are the children of which nodes, but just as text - not embedded into an image or a dot file. Technically a dot file is text, but it is designed for rendering an image and is hard to read if all you want is to get an idea of the tree. Is there any export function in scikit-learn that will produce some kind of human-readable description of a `DecisionTreeClassifier`?

My fallback plan is to write my own function by modifying the `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz()` source, but I'm wondering if something already exists.

Comment: Maybe this example can help: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html

Comment: Vivek Kumar that does help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer because I can't post comments.

This [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html#sklearn.tree.export_text) is to a scikit learn method `sklearn.tree.export_text` which should output text according to this code chunk I took from the page:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
>>> from sklearn.tree.export import export_text
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> X = iris['data']
>>> y = iris['target']
>>> decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=2)
>>> decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X, y)
>>> r = export_text(decision_tree, feature_names=iris['feature_names'])
>>> print(r)
|--- petal width (cm) <= 0.80
|   |--- class: 0
|--- petal width (cm) >  0.80
|   |--- petal width (cm) <= 1.75
|   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- petal width (cm) >  1.75
|   |   |--- class: 2
...
```

Downside is I tried using it but this happens:

```
from sklearn.tree.export import export_text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'export_text'
```

Maybe you can get a better result than me, and if you can please let me know. I am using scikit-learn==0.20.3